# Should I use "build" insted of "got it made" for the following sentence-

Tags: phrase-meaning

King Ghadsi of Jaisalmer got the lake made 650 years ago with the help of the people(when will I use "got it made")

Comment: I think ***got, to get [something] done*** is a relatively informal / colloquial usage, so you should probably say *[he] **had it made / built***. But you haven't told us what "**it**" is, so I can't say which of ***made, built*** is appropriate. If "it" is anything that would be called a "building", that's the word to use. If it's something like a *statue* or a *landscaped garden*, that would probably be ***made***. But for some "constructions" (such as a *bridge*), you could use either verb.

Comment: FF You are absolutely correct that we do not know for certain what "it" represents, but the reference is probably to an artificial lake originally built as a reservoir. "Making a reservoir" sounds odd to me. "Making a pond" does not sound odd. But, if my guess is correct, this lake is a lot bigger than a pond and seems in part to be bound by walls. So I am going with "build."

Comment: Thank you FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica

Answer (score 2):

> He got the machine made

means

> He caused the machine to be made without personally doing the work

In the US at least, it is idiomatic but very informal. You can say the **same thing without a hint of informality** by saying

> He had the machine made

or

> He caused the machine to be made

With respect to *"make"*, it has a very broad field of meaning, but it would not normally be used to mean "*construct a building"*. The natural verb to use would be *"build"*

So to be natural without sounding too informal, try

> King Ghadsi of Jaisalmer had it built ...

Comment: Please elaborate your answer

Comment: In what respect do you want me to elaborate? Why did I recemmend "built" instead of "made"? Or why did I recommend "had" instead of "got"?

Comment: I have no idea what your latest question means. Your original statement said that King Ghadsi caused the people to make something. If that is wrong, I was merely following what you said.